# How to use data in an ArrayList and integer fields after a program finishes executing?

Tags: java, list

I am trying to create a GUI application to manage ticket sales. Every time a ticket is sold, for example, I should update the information about that ticket in my ArrayList of tickets and it should persist after I close the program. I currently have a Data class defined that looks like the following:

```java
public class Database {
    static ArrayList<Ticket> soldTickets;
    static int valueOfAllSoldTickets;

    public Database() {
        soldTickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
        valueOfAllSoldTickets = 0;
    }
}
```

I don't actually want to instantiate a `Database` object multiple times, it should just happen one time to hold the data that the user of the GUI will be working with. I just want it to be some type of structure I can use to have a bunch of different pieces of information stored on the hard drive (like more `ints` and `lists`) which I envision being more fields in a class like this. But how would I write my changes to this int field to the hard drive and be able to access it with a method like `getTotalSales()`? This method would be within my Database class.

Once I get to the point where I have main method where everything is running in, I also don't want to be creating a new ArrayList of tickets every single time I run the program. This leads me to ask how do I instantiate an ArrayList of tickets just one time, and not have it happen again, and then use that already-instantiated list to add and remove from it as I need to do so. This list also needs to be stored on the hard drive of the computer it is running on. If I am approaching this in the wrong way, I would appreciate if someone could tell me an alternative way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You want your program to save a list to disk, then read it when it starts up?

Comment: I think what you need is serialization. ArrayList class already implemented Serializable interface, so make sure that your Ticket class implement Serializable and all the fields can be serialized. Then you could use ObjectOutputStream to persist your data to the disk. More info could be found in the java document.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `FasterXML/jackson`

```
private static final String TICKET_NAME = "ticker.json";
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // 1 start,init the list of ticket
    File file = new File(TICKET_NAME);
    TypeReference<List<Ticket>> reference = new TypeReference<List<Ticket>>() {
    };
    List<Ticket> tickets = mapper.readValue(file, reference);
    file.delete();

    // 2 stop store the tickets into file
    File newFile = new File(TICKET_NAME);
    mapper.writeValue(newFile, tickets);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your ArrayList to disk as a file if Ticket class implements Serializable interface. Here is sample code to write to file and read it from file

```
Writing



ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();

        tickets.add(new Ticket(...));
        tickets.add(new Ticket(...));

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("TicketsData.obj");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(tickets);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

Reading



try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("TicketsData.obj");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            tickets = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Update - 2 : Logic to optimize write to disk calls.

If ticket class is bulky & ArrayList will have more than 1000 elements

->Ticket class will have its own writeToDisk, which will save the current object as ticket_xxx.obj in tickets folder.

->Suppose if ticket_id is 1234 it will first check ticket_1234.obj already exists in tickets folder. If it exists it will check the last update date of the file and the Obj last update date col, will overwrite only if there is a new version.

-> There will be a util class TicketSaveHelper writeToDisk & readFromDisk. writeToDisk will take ArrayList and call writeToDisk on individual tickets. readFromDisk will read all the .obj files from the dir and return an ArrayList.

Comment: More that serialization is something that's mostly still included for backwards compatability and not a good idea to use; see Effective Java for a full discussion. One of the problems is that if the underlying class changes, you can't deserialize it anymore and your data is lost, or you at least need to put effort in to recover it.

Comment: If I add something to the list after I write it to the disk, do I have to write the whole ArrayList to the disk again?

Comment: With the sample code I have given Yes total list needs to be written. If you want to further optimize (Only if your Ticket object is bulky & your ArrayList contains more then 1000 elements) you can have writeObject at Ticket class level and store it individually and let a factory class write & read them. This way only the new Tickets added to ArrayList will get saved. Let me update the answer.